# Wordpress - How to programmatically (SQL) duplicate a post

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have to import over 100k pages. I wrote a SQL query that basically just duplicates the wp_posts and wp_post_meta entry for one specific post.

This works, the page is visible and so on, but it almost looks like it has no styling and -or something is wrong with my Elementor build page.

Does anyone know if I am missing tables or something?

I cannot use any existing plugins for this as they all charge money for something that I will only use once, besides that, I would like to learn it myself

Hope someone can help me out.

So in total what I did was:

1. Duplicate 1 row from wp_posts with new title, content and a unique id
2. Duplicate 16 rows from wp_post_meta with the post_id pointing to the correct id

This shows the page both in the backend and on the website (as a visitor) but the styling seems to be missing.

Hope someone can explain to me how to duplicate a specific post by using SQL queries.

What I copied from wp_post_meta

```
_edit_lock
_wp_page_template
_edit_last
_elementor_edit_mode
_elementor_template_type
_elementor_version
_elementor_data
_happyaddons_elements_cache
_elementor_page_assets
_pingme
_encloseme
_elementor_css
```

I asked this question at Elementor too but no response unfortunately.

Comment: If you want to copy and move pages with elementor - then elementor has come out with its own feature called export/import kit - Youo can make a kit of you webpage, decide what you want to move, and then import it on another elementor site - Then you get it all. But I don't know if it can handle 100K pages.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, that is awesome but still... should be able to do it with a simple query right? I mean it is not a secret or anything I guess so I really would like to know how to get it working haha :D but thanks for the headsup, ill look into the export/import kit.